# An error regarding a member in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting the following error:`'ViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'inputField'`

for this line of code: `var possibleGuess : Int? = inputField.text.toInt()`

in the body of this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var output: UITextView!
    var guesses : UInt = 0;
    var number : UInt32 = 0;
    var gameover = false;
    var possibleGuess : Int? = inputField.text.toInt()

    let MAX_GUESSES = 8;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        number = generateNewNumber()
        consoleOut("I'm thinking of a number...\n")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func consoleOut(text : String) {
        output.text = output.text + text;
    }

    func generateNewNumber() -> UInt32 {
        return arc4random_uniform(100) + 1
    }

    func clearInput() {
        inputField.text = ""
    }

    @IBAction func guess(sender: UIButton) {
    }
}
```

I'm looking at my code and clearly, I have the member `inputField` declared with this line of code, `@IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextField!` But I am still getting an error. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Put  var possibleGuess : Int? = inputField.text.toInt() in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! How come it works when I put in viewDidLoad method and doesn't work when I declare it globally?

Comment: var possibleGuess : Int? = inputField.text.toInt() What will be the value of possibleGuess variable as you are using !?

Answer (score 0):

Put member

var possibleGuess : Int? //Global scope

And in viewDidLoad

possibleGuess = inputField.text.toInt();